# Unconfirmed transaction for 6 days now. need assistance for using CPFP

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, mempool

I have an unconfirmed transaction that has been sitting there for 6 days now.
The fees only got higher sins i've made the transaction and i do not feel comfortabel waiting.
I'm unable to use RBF sins trezor thus not support this and i'm nor sure on how to use CPFP
the TX is : 8b5032bcc435ebc612128fb66c30d85af19febd6f03dafb9114253dac6a9e0cf

After the transaction i've noticed that the recieving wallet is a legacy one, while i've send it from a segwit. could that cause any problems?

Is there any risk comming with waiting any longer?

Thx

Comment: 1) You need to setup Electurm with Trezor: https://wiki.trezor.io/Apps:Electrum and https://wiki.trezor.io/Child_Pays_For_Parent_(CPFP) 2) Not a problem 3) You can also wait but the fee rate is very low, I wouldn't.

Comment: What if my balance is 0? can i do an CPFP then?

Comment: When will my transaction be removed, so i can get my BTC available again in the wallet i've send it from

Comment: If "balance 0" is the case, If you sent to your wallet, you need to CPFP from that wallet. Otherwise, the recipient should CPFP it. At least two weeks from when you submitted the transaction. Instead, I would try submitting it here https://www.viabtc.com/tools/txaccelerator?lang=en_US every hour sharp (AA:00).

Comment: I have tried CPFP and apperently its not an option for me. i do not have the nessecary green or yellow output address. So the only thing i can do is wait till it got rejected i'm afraid. Question is then, how long will this take.

Comment: 14 days after you first published it

Comment: Thx, i'll wait for that then.... we are halfway this period

Comment: It has been 14 days now, the transaction is still stuck in the mempool and pending... in the meantime the BTC can not be used. is this still normal?

Comment: Apologies, someone (evil) is re-broadcasting low fee transactions. Your only hope seems to be reaching the recipient and asking them to do CPFP and deduce the CPFP fee from your payment. Otherwise it might take even a month for your transaction to be accepted. Meanwhile, I am trying to reach the Bitcoin Core developers so that maybe one day it becomes impossible to re-publish low fee transactions

Comment: What? that should not even be possible right? so how do i the CPFP as the receiver? The reciever wallet is a Safepal

Comment: i've just noticed that on the reciever side the transaction is gone, so he can't do a CPFP then i guess.

Comment: but on the wallet i've send it from, it remains visible as unconfirmed

Comment: Can he please check again?

Comment: Hi, So in the recieving wallet still nothing and in the sending wallet still unconfirmed and therefore still blocked.

Comment: OK then, let's do CPFP. Would you mind downloading the Electrum wallet and using it temporarily, then creating a new seed/account on your hardware wallet and transfer to it again?

Comment: You need to follow the steps here: https://bitcoinelectrum.com/restoring-your-standard-wallet-from-seed/ Choose "legacy" when you see a list. And when you import the seed enable "BIP39". Don't change the derivation path. If you see your unconfirmed transaction, you should be able to CPFP it by spending it (to your new account, you need to open a newer one in your hardware wallet now, since now coins are accessible to your PC)

Comment: If you don't see your unconfirmed tx there once it's synced (green on bottom-right corner) go to Load > Transaction from text and paste https://blockchain.info/rawtx/8b5032bcc435ebc612128fb66c30d85af19febd6f03dafb9114253dac6a9e0cf?format=hex

Comment: Hi, it finaly came true, got 8 confimations... i'll be able to sleep again. Anyone did something? i noticed the mempool size finaly decended. maybe that wy. Anyway problem solved. thanks alot for you support

Comment: Wow, yes that must be the cause it is confrmed now. you're welcome :)